# Type for TypeORM Raw Entity: CamelToSnake / ValueOf Exact Matching / Property-Method inference

Tags: typescript, typeorm, type-inference

Summary: Generating Types for Raw Return Types in TypeORM

Hello, I'm working with TypeORM and have a question about handling raw return types. When using getRawOne and getRawMany functions, the return includes strings composed of class names and properties, which are concatenated with an underscore ('_').

For example:

```js
export class TestUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    verified: boolean;
}
const userRepository = getRepository(TestUser);

// getRawOne is not support type. just return any type. I want to disclose this return type.
const loaedRawTestUser = await userRepository.createQueryBuilder('testUser')
    .addSelect('COUNT(*()', 'myAliasForAllUserCount')
    .getRawOne();

/**
 * {
 *   testUser_id: number;
 *   testUser_name: string;
 *   testUser_verified: boolean;
 * }
 */
console.log(loaedRawUser);
```

The issue comprises three parts:

- Converting camelCase to snake_case.
- Inferring the class name for the composition of the return string.
- Exact value matching for the converted properties (Entity key).

The first part has been resolved.

I've implemented a camelCase to snake_case type inferer as follows:

```js
export type CamelCaseToSnakeCase<
    T extends string,
    Joiner extends '' | '_' = ''
> = T extends `${infer Character}${infer Rest}`
    ? Character extends Uppercase<Character>
        ? `${Joiner}${Lowercase<Character>}${CamelCaseToSnakeCase<Rest, '_'>}`
        : `${Character}${CamelCaseToSnakeCase<Rest, '_'>}`
    : '';
```

Is there something way?

---

Additional Requirements if it can be.

When TestUser class has method like this:

```js
export class TestUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    verified: boolean;
    
    getNameIfVerified(): {
        return this.verified ? this.name : 'not verified'
    }
}

const typeormRawColumTestSample: Partial<TypeORMRawColumns<TestUser, 'TestUser'>> = {
    testUser_id: 1,
    //  when testUser_id: '1' should be error.
    testUser__get_name_if_verified // should be error.
}
```

How can I exclude methods from a Type in TypeScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've partially resolved the second issue, but it's not completely solved yet.

```js
/**
 * Not yet typescript is not support inferring class name from Type T.
 * So, I regard programmer must input entity class name as hardcoding. 
 */
export type TypeORMRawColumns<
    Entity,
    EntityClassName extends string,
    ConvertedPropertyAsSnake = `${Uncapitalize<EntityClassName>}_${CamelCaseToSnakeCase<
        Extract<keyof Entity, string>
    >}`,
    ValueType = Entity[keyof Entity]
> = {
    [key in Extract<ConvertedPropertyAsSnake, string>]: ValueType;
};

// Second parameter is hard coded for class name.
const test1: TypeORMRawColumns<TestUser, 'TestUser'> = {
    testUser_id: 1,
    testUser_name: 'john',
    testUser_verified: true
};

// But by union type, it is not safe from other property type.
// Expected error but it is not.
const test2: TypeORMRawColumns<TestUser, 'TestUser'> = {
    testUser_id: 'it is not type-safe. Because of ValueOf is union type of Entity properties.',
    // like number | string | boolean
    testUser_name: 'john',
    testUser_verified: true
};
```